# Inheritance: Proper initialization to store values into a HashMap

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap, java.util.scanner, abstract

I am working with separate programs, one will read in a `.txt` file and then that same program will store the read in values into another program containing a `HashMap`. The program that contains the `HashMap`, is named `Hero.java` and is an `abstract class`. I have a program that extends that program called `Cop.java`. With that in mind, I would like to know the proper way to transfer the files read in from my `GameDriver.java` over to the `HashMap`.

To my knowledge, one way of doing this is initializing `Cop.java` like so,

```
Cop N = new Cop();
```

and then performing a method call

```
N.rescue();
```

What is the proper way to add the read in values? Can I use a solution similar to that one? I am trying to get the `String cn` to be stored in the map `name` and `int pts` to be stored in `points` below. Thanks for all answers and please let me know if you need any clarification. I will post my `GameDriver.java` code as well as my `Hero.java` code **Thanks!!**

**GameDriver.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         Cop N = new Cop();
         String s;
         File f = new File (args[0]);
         Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
         while (input.hasNext()) {
                s = input.next();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) { Character c1 = new Cop();
                                                 System.out.println(c1); }

                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) { String cn = input.next(); //HashMap name
                                               int pts = input.nextInt(); //HashMap points
                                               N.rescue();}

         }

  }
}
```

**Hero.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Hero extends Character
{
   private String heroname1;
   public Hero() {
          heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; //the default player name
   }
   HashMap name = new HashMap<String, GameDriver>();
   HashMap points = new HashMap<Integer, GameDriver>();

   public Hero(String newhero) {
          if (newhero.length() > 0) {
               heroname1 = newhero;
          } else { heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; } //defaulted as protagonist
   }

   public String getHeroName() {
          return heroname1; //return the name
   }

   public String rescue() { //class to rescue people or things
          return heroname1 + " rescued " + name + " for " + points + "!";
   }

   public String toString() { //print
          return heroname1;

   }
}
```

**Overall Objective**

I realize I haven't added in my overall objective: The purpose is reading in a file to create a new hero (usually only one) and having them save multiple people/things in this hypothetical game. For example, if the file says

```
c h Rick Grimes //create hero
r Carl 100 //rescue for x amount of points
```

I want that data to be stored in a map or something and be outputted like so:

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl for 100 points!
```

also note this all must be done through inheritance

Comment: It looks to me like you're very confused about what `HashMap` is for and how it works.  Please look over some information on maps and sets in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).  You may want a `List` or a `Set` instead.  Also, a `Map` holds more than one name, but you're trying to print only one in your `rescue()` method--is that right?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but something needs work.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to store names and point values into something and be printed out together accordingly, like for example `you saved Carl for 100 points!` and yes I haven't used a map before so if there is an easier way I would be very much interested to know

Comment: But do you want each `Hero` to store multiple names and points?  Or does it just need to store one at a time?  Your problem statement is not clear at all; I'm afraid I can't give you much help since I really have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I suggest your going in right way by using `composition` over `inheritance` and `rescue()` should have `params` like `String name,int points` and in that you should initialize map by `HashMap newmap = new HashMap();`
      
     `// populate hash map
      newmap.put("hero1", 10);
      newmap.put("hero2", 100); //like wise`

Comment: Please see overall objective edit in my question perhaps that will help

Comment: The `Hero` class should definitely not know the `GameDriver` class. It does not use it anywhere in the code you provided, and more importantly, it's poor design.

Comment: I dont know what you mean "not know" because it certainly doesn't. `GameDriver` calls it thats about it. `Hero` `Cop` and `Character` are all part of inheritance the `Driver` simply runs it.