# Method not returning to user (inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap, java.util.scanner, method-call

I am trying to read in values to a `HashMap` from a Driver program to a separate `abstract` program. After that, I want the contents to be printed to the user. However, when I call the method nothing happens

**GameDriver**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String s;
        File f = new File (args[0]);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            s = input.next();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) { 
                Hero c1 = new Cop();
                System.out.println(c1); 
            }

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) { 
                Hero c2 = new Cop();
                String cn = input.next();
                int pts = input.nextInt();
                c2.newMap.put(cn, pts);
                c2.rescue();
                System.out.println(c2);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**Hero.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Hero extends Character
{
   private String heroname1;
   public Hero() {
          heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; //the default player name
   }
   HashMap<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

   public Hero(String newhero) {
          if (newhero.length() > 0) {
               heroname1 = newhero;
          } else { heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; } //defaulted as protagonist
   }

   public String getHeroName() {
          return heroname1; //return the name
   }

   public String rescue() { //class to rescue people or things
          return " rescued " + newMap + "pts!";
   }

   public String toString() { //print
          return heroname1 + rescue();

   }
}
```

The Driver reads in a .txt file here is a sample

**.TXT**

```
c h Rick Grimes//create hero
r Carl 100 //rescue name and point value
```

and finally my output vs desired output

**Current Output**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes
```

**Desired Output**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!
```

Thank you to anyone who helps! Ask if you need any clarification

**EDIT Cop.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Cop extends Hero {
   public Cop() {
         super();
   }
   public void hero1(String newhero) {
          newhero = getHeroName(); //get name from the Hero class
   }
   public void lieDetect() { //unique ability for cops
          System.out.println("Cops can tell the good from the bad");
   }
}
```

Comment: Add the code of your Cop Class. It could help.

Comment: Ok, added to my edit

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518563/inheritance-proper-initialization-to-store-values-into-a-hashmap ??

Comment: That question was sorta answered but yes you can find all my code there. It's a little updated though on here

Comment: Have you run your code? Because I have done it and I obtain the following output : `Rick Grimes rescued {}pts!
Rick Grimes rescued {Carl=100}pts!` It's almost what you are expecting.

Comment: That is very strange. When I ran it earlier it gave me what I have under current output. Do you mind if I change my question then? I still just want what is under my desired output, meaning the first line of output only saying `Rick Grimes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GameDriver :

```
if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) { 
    Hero c1 = new Cop();
    System.out.println(c1.getHeroName()); 
}
```

The rescue method in the class Hero :

```
public String rescue() { //class to rescue people or things
       String toReturn = "";
       for(String _key : newMap.keySet()) {
           toReturn += " rescued " + _key + " " + newMap.get(_key) + "pts!";
       }
       return toReturn;
   }
```

And I obtain the desired output.